# Filtrar Por Fechas en SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema algo confuso.

**Primero:** Quiero saber cuantos días de pago le corresponden a una persona segun sus asistencias dentro del periodo actual.

Tabla **`usuarios`**:

```
id  Nombre fecha_ingreso
1   Juan   01-01-2018
2   Pedro  01-01-2018
```

Tabla **`asistencias`**, donde `1` es asistencia y `0` falta:

```
id asist fecha
1  0     02-08-2018
1  1     03-08-2018
2  1     02-08-2018
2  1     03-08-2018
```

Mi tabla **`periodo`** contiene la siguiente info:

```
idp  diai        diaf
1    30-07-2018  12-08-2018
```

Mi **`script`** (funcionando correctamente, Nota: esta en SQL server ):

```
$conn ~~ aqui se conecta a la base de datos ~~
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
while ($usuario = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
$id=$usuario['id'];

  $sql_periodo_inicial = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT top 1 diai FROM periodo order by diai DESC");
   if($t_periodo_c=sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_periodo_inicial)) {
                                $t_perido_diai=$t_periodo_c['diai'];

                            } 
  $sql_periodo_inicial = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT top 1 diaf FROM periodo order by diaf DESC");
   if($t_periodo_c=sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql_periodo_inicial)) {
                                $t_perido_diaf=$t_periodo_c['diaf'];
                            }  


$sql_asistencia_asistidas2 = "SELECT * FROM asistencia 
                where id=$id 
                and fecha >= '$t_perido_diai' 
                and fecha <= '$t_perido_diaf' 
                and asistencia = '1'";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt2 = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql_asistencia_asistidas2 , $params, $options );
$dias_trabajados_ttAsist = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt2 ); 

echo $dias_trabajados_ttAsist;
}
```

Con esto en mi tabla me muestra correctamente los resultados Juan 1 asistencia y Pedro 2 dentro del periodo actual

***Pregunta***

**Segundo**: Si Andrés (`id=3`) entro despues de la fecha de corte ('`diaf' = 12`) pero antes de la quincena que sería el día 15  por ejemplo el día 13 de Agosto del 2018.

Esta persona tendria 2 dias trabajados que no se le pagaran el dia 15 pero se le sumaran a su siguiente quincenta del dia 30.

¿Qué tendría que agregar a mi consulta para encontrar los días adicionales de Andrés?:

```
$sql_asistencia_asistidas2 = "SELECT * FROM asistencia 
                where id=$id 
                and fecha >= '$t_perido_diai' 
                and fecha <= '$t_perido_diaf' 
                and asistencia = '1'";
```

Ésto es con la finalidad de que en mi tabla pueda generar automáticamente este valor , pero más importante poder identificar si hay algún error a la hora de dar de alta a usuarios.

Comment: No entiendo, si Andres entro  a trabajar el 13 de Agosto, no deberian esos dias ser contados para el siguiente periodo? O sea no contarlos en el periodo que termina el 12.

Comment: Hola alanfcm , exacto es decir la siguiente quincena (dia 30) sele pagaran 15 dias +2 (total 17) esta algo confuso la verda a mi me lo explicaron de una manera algo complicada y tarde mucho en aterrizar la idea xD

Comment: La unica forma que se me ocurre seria agregar un campo extra a la tabla `asistencias` llamado `pagado` con valor 1 si ya fue pagado y 0 si no.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna forma de control contable en tu modelo de datos? Aunque no la haya ahora es muy probable que vayas a necesitarlo, entonces enfoca la solución del problema pensando en eso. Vas a poder encontrar soluciones a medio término, hechas casi a mano. Creo que en estos casos se requiere una solución global y pensando en una futura evolución del modelo de datos. Más tarde te dirán que se quiere relacionar los datos actuales con una tabla `contabilidad` y/o  con una tabla `nomina`... entonces tu solución a medio término no servirá de nada y tendrás que rediseñar tu estructura de datos.

Comment: Si actual mente el modelo de nomina es manual, y comotal tiene muchas inconsistencias actual mente lo primero es manejar de manera logica los peridodos con las nominas. creo que si habra que ajustar campos